# AI Steering Behavior XNA

Tags: c#, xna, artificial-intelligence, behavior

How can i merge all the behaviors in one entity?

for example an entity wandering for a limited time or distance then change its behavior to arrive.... I'm debugging it for weeks but suddenly i failed :( can someone help me fix my issue? :)

here's a link for the source code :) i've downloaded it on the net itself - [SourceCode](http://www.mediafire.com/?hk8kbwdimoinkdi)

Comment: You need to be more specific in what you need.  Most people won't take the time to go look at your source code and figure it out.

Comment: Please try to write an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) compliant question (see [http://sscce.org/](http://sscce.org/)). It helps you narrow down your issue, makes it easier for us to help you and it could even make you realize where you've made a mistake, thus answering your own question. It's always good to try and isolate your problem!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest reviewing and studying the original paper by *Craig Reynolds* which describes the steering behaviors, and how to "merge" them. It includes reference to an open source C++ implementation called OpenSteer:
http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/

Specifically, I assume that you are referring to the *[Flocking](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/)* behaviors, which combine: Separation, Alignment, and Cohesion.